# Python palindrome code doesn't return anything

Tags: python-2.7

Why?
It returns:

```
  if word[0] != word[-1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I change "print "Palindrome"" to "return True" and "return False" it returns nothing at all.

```
import sys

exstring = "f"
data = list(exstring)

def palindrome(word):
    if len(word) < 2:
        print "Palindrome"
    if word[0] != word[-1]:
        print "Not Palindrome"
    return palindrome(word[1:-1])

palindrome(data)
```

Comment: Change those prints to returns. Then, change `palindrome(data)` to `print(palindrome(data))`

Comment: Shouldn't you have an `if/elif` statement? Plus a return when a Palindrome is found or not found

Comment: If you want it to return True or False, why does not any line say "return True" or "return False"?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an elif in there like Hypnic Jerk mentioned. Second you need to return after your prints.

Working code:

```
import sys

exstring = "radar"
data = list(exstring)

def palindrome(word):
    if len(word) < 2:
        print "Palindrome"
        return True
    elif word[0] != word[-1]:
        print "Not Palindrome"
        return False
    return palindrome(word[1:-1])

palindrome(data)
```

Comment: You don't need `elif` because the first `if` clause `return`s. So `if` is sufficient when you add the `return`.

Comment: Yep! Worked without elif, just by adding returns. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

```
def palindrome(word):
    if len(word) < 2:
        return True
    if word[0] != word[-1]:
        return False
    return palindrome(word[1:-1])
```

You do not need elif in this case. It's just good practice. The second if statement will not be reached unless the first is false anyway. More "correct" (but still completely equivalent) is:

```
def palindrome(word):
    if len(word) < 2:
        return True
    elif word[0] != word[-1]:
        return False
    else
        return palindrome(word[1:-1])
```

Furthermore, it's good practice to only let the function decide if it's a palindrome or not, and not print it. Instead, you should use it like this:

```
if palindrome(word):
    print "Palindrome"
else
    print "Not palindrome"
```

Don't mix functionality unless you have a good reason.